# selecting a new month from dropdown menu clears the date dropdown in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, drop-down-menu

I have three dropdown menus representing date, month and year of birth:

```
<input-select
  id="dateOfBirth"
  label="Day"
  :name="'dateOfBirth' | hashcode"
  :option-default="select dat"
  :option-list="birthDates"
  :v-model="birthdate"
  :value="birthdate"</input-select> 

<input-select
  id="monthOfBirth"
  label="Month"
  :name="'monthOfBirth' | hashcode"
  :option-default="select month"
  :option-list="birthMonth"
  v-model="birthmonth"
  :value="birthMonth"></input-select> 

<input-select 
  id="yearOfBirth"
  label="Year"
  :name="'yearOfBirth' | hashcode"
  :option-list="birthYears"
  :option-default="select year"
  v-model="birthyear"
  :value="birthyear"
></input-select>
```

I want the values in birthDates array (which shows the dates in date dropdown menu) to be dynamic and be chosen based on the month (for ex Nov. has 28 days where as Jan. has 31) to do this I have written the following piece of code:

```
data: function () {
    return {
    //initiating the array which would show the dates
    birthdate:[],
    numDates:''
...
  methods: {
    //the function that would repopulate the birthdate[] array
    birthdateValueList(){
      //erasing the values of the existing array
      this.birthdates = []
      //adding new values
      let i = 1;
      //numDates is defined in another function based on the month selected, please see below
      while (i <= this.numDates){
        this.birthdates.push(i);
        i ++;
      }
...
  // watching the birthmonth drop down and setting the number days for that month
  // this is where we define numDates
  watch: {
    birthmonth:function(){
      if(this.birthmonth === "April" || this.birthmonth === "June" || this.birthmonth === "September" || this.birthmonth === "November"){
        this.numDates = 30
      }else if (this.birthmonth === "February" && this.leapYear){
          this.numDates = 29
        }
         else if(this.birthmonth === "February" && !this.leapYear){
          this.numDates = 28
      }
      else {
        this.numDates = 31
      }
...
  // and then a computed property to do some formatting and returning the final array
  computed: {
    birthDates: function(){
      var list = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.birthdates));
      var birthdateDates = this.generateNewList(list);
      return birthdateDates;
    },
```

This code works perfectly and all but the problem is whenever I select a new month, the date dropdown clears and doesn't show anything eventhough in the console I can see its value `birthdate` doesn't change! What's the problem here?

Comment: Make sure you are `v-model` `birthdate` is not being updated anywhere else in the code. Either in computed or watch. That could be the reason.

Comment: Also, I have noticed you are using `v-model` and `:value` both. Try removing `:value`